# How to reshape a 183,223,040x4 matrix into 140 matrices of dimensions 1145x1145 without MemoryError?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, memory, large-data

I have a matrix of dimensions 183,223,040x4 with the variables showed below. There are 140 different values in 'REG', and 1145 different values of both 'SAMAC' and 'SAMAC.1'

I want to iterate over REG to get 140 matrices of size 1145*1145, with the right 'VALUE' in it.

I have tried the following:

-loop over countries

-create empty matrix 1145*1145, indexed with SAMAC and with column names SAMAC.1

-go line by line of the current dataframe

-check the value of SAMAC (rows) and SAMAC.1 (columns)

-locate SAMAC and SAMAC.1 in the empty matrix and assigned the corresponding VALUE

```py
import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as dd

all_sam=dd.read_csv(r'C:\GP2\all_sams_trial.csv',skiprows=1)

all_sam.head()
   SAMAC SAMAC.1  REG  Value
0  m_pdr   m_pdr  aus    0.0
1  m_wht   m_pdr  aus    0.0
2  m_gro   m_pdr  aus    0.0
3  m_v_f   m_pdr  aus    0.0
4  m_osd   m_pdr  aus    0.0

countries=list(all_sam["REG"].unique().compute())
col_names=list(all_sam["SAMAC"].unique().compute())

for country in countries:
    df=pd.DataFrame(0,index=col_names,columns=col_names)

    sam=all_sam[all_sam["REG"]==country].compute()

    for index,row in sam.iterrows():
        row_index=str(row["SAMAC"])
        col_index=str(row["SAMAC.1"])
        df.loc[row_index,col_index]=row['Value']
        print(index)

    df.to_csv(country+"_SAM.csv")
```

The problem is that it takes way to long to compute (around 2 days). Is there a way to speed this up?

Answer (score 0):

Update 1: After understanding OP's problem of slow computation because of large size of dataframe, here's the update.

1. Check the dtypes of columns using `all_sam.dtypes` and the size (in Mb) of your dataframe using:

   ```
   all_sam.memory_usage(deep=True) / 1024 ** 2
   ```
2. Consider changing the column name 'SAMAC.1' to 'SAMAC_1' as it could cause error in the following lines. Before processing change the dtypes of 'REG', 'SAMAC' and 'SAMAC_1' to 'categorical':

   ```
   all_sam.REG = all_sam.REG.astype('category')
   all_sam.SAMAC = all_sam.SAMAC.astype('category')
   all_sam.SAMAC_1 = all_sam.SAMAC_1.astype('category')
   ```
3. Depending on your requirement, you can downcast the dtype of the 'Value' column to float16, int16, int8, etc. using the below code:

   ```
   all_sam.Value = all_sam.Value.astype('float16')
   ```
4. Check the size again.

   ```
   all_sam.memory_usage(deep=True) / 1024 ** 2
   ```

Hopefully, this will enable faster computation.

### Ref: [towardsdatascience.com](https://towardsdatascience.com/make-working-with-large-dataframes-easier-at-least-for-your-memory-6f52b5f4b5c4)

I have taken a small example dataframe to put up a solution to your problem.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame( {'REG':['A','A','A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','B','B'], 'SAMAC1':['a','a','a','b','b','b','c','c','c','d','d','d'], 'SAMAC':['p','q','r','p','q','r','p','q','r','p','q','r'], 'value':[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]})
array_ = df[['REG','SAMAC1','SAMAC']].values.transpose()
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(array_, names=('REG', 'SAMAC1','SAMAC'))
df2 = df['value']
df2.index=index
country_labels = df2.index.get_level_values(0)
country_unique = country_labels.unique()
result_arr = []
for c in country_unique:
    df3 = df2[df2.index.get_level_values(0) == c]
    result_arr.append(df3.unstack().values)
result_arr = np.array(result_arr)
print(result_arr.shape)
```

Output: (2,2,3)

Comment: Many thanks @jatin! The time issue appears to remain however. Each step takes very long (simply running array_ = df[['REG','SAMAC1','SAMAC']].values.transpose() takes about 12 minutes). This is because the initial matrix is very big

Comment: Would you mind sharing your computer specs? Thanks :)

Comment: Can you run this command to display the storage memory usage by your dataframe? 
all_sam.memory_usage(deep=True)/ 1024 ** 2

Comment: Loading the dataframe with pandas take about 10mins. And my computer is OK (8GB RAM, Intel I5-5th generation). The csv from which the data is loaded weight 4.4GB, and once loaded the dataframe:

    `all_sam.memory_usage(deep=True)/1024**2`

    `Out[4]:`
 
    `Index          0.000076`

    `SAMAC      11126.227417`

    `SAMAC.1    11126.227417`

    `REG        10484.106445`

    `Value       1397.880859`

Comment: I am afraid it is not working, as a "memory error" arises.

Comment: I realize that using dask is more efficient.

Comment: How would that be implemented?

Comment: A bit busy these days. Try the following after renaming 'SAMAC.1' to 'SAMAC_1'. Will post complete answer later. 

`import dask.dataframe as dd`
`all_sam=dd.read_csv(r'C:\GP2\all_sams_trial.csv',skiprows=1)`
`all_sam.REG = all_sam.REG.astype('category')`
`all_sam.SAMAC = all_sam.SAMAC.astype('category')`
`all_sam.SAMAC_1 = all_sam.SAMAC_1.astype('category')`
`all_sam.Value = all_sam.Value.astype('float16')`
`all_sam=all_sam.compute()`
`all_sam.memory_usage(deep=True) / 1024 ** 2`

and then maybe you can try following my above answer.